# Modelica: Mixing connectors and direct inputs

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

The following Modelica package - while neither being particularly useful nor interesting - does not yield any warnings.

```
package P
  connector C
    Real c;
  end C;
  model A
    input C x;
    output Real y;
  equation 
    y = x.c;
  end A;
  model B
    input C inp;
    output C out;
    A a;
  equation 
    a.x = inp;
    out.c = a.y;
  end B;
end P;
```

However, when `A` does not use connectors as in the following case, there is a warning: *The following input lacks a binding equation: `a.x`*. Clearly, there is a binding equation for `a.x`. Why is there such a warning?

```
package P
  connector C
    Real c;
  end C;
  model A
    input Real x;
    output Real y;
  equation 
    y = x;
  end A;
  model B
    input C inp;
    output C out;
    A a;
  equation 
    a.x = inp.c;
    out.c = a.y;
  end B;
end P;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is that there is **not** a binding equation.  There is only an ordinary equation.  A binding equation is one that is applied as a modification to the element, e.g.

```
model B
  input C inp;
  output C out;
  A a(x=inp.c) "Binding equation";
equation 
  out.c = a.y;
end B;
```

Note that in general, if two things are connectors, they should not be equated, they should be connected.  That will help you avoid this issue.  So in your first version of `B`:

```
model B
  input C inp;
  output C out;
  A a;
equation
  connect(a.x, inp); 
  out.c = a.y;
end B;
```

The reason for the binding equation restriction has to do with making sure components are balanced.  You can read more about that in the specification or in [Modelica by Example](http://book.xogeny.com/components/components/component_models/#balanced-components).  By using it as a binding equation, it makes it clear that this equation can be used to solve for this variable (*i.e.,* the term in the equation containing that variable won't vanish or be ill-conditioned).